# pandas dataframe create a new column whose values are based on groupby sum on another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column `amount_0_flag` for a `df`, the values in that column are based on `groupby` another column `key`, for which if `amount` `sum` is 0, assigned `True` to `amount_0_flag`, otherwise `False`. The `df` looks like,

```
key    amount    amount_0_flag    negative_amount
1       1.0      True             False
1       1.0      True             True
2       2.0      False            True
2       3.0      False            False
2       4.0      False            False
```

so when `df.groupby('key')`, cluster with `key=1`, will be assigned `True` to `amount_0_flag` for each element of the cluster, since within the cluster, one element has negative 1 and another element has postive 1 as their `amount`s.

```
df.groupby('key')['amount'].sum()
```

only gives the sum of `amount` for each cluster not considering values in `negative_amount` and I am wondering how to also find the cluster and its rows with `0` sum amounts consdering `negative_amount` values using pandas/numpy.

Comment: Do you mind to write the original dataframe and the output you are looking forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this where I created a 'new_column' showing the comparison to your 'amount_0_flag':

```
df['new_column'] = (df.assign(amount_n = df.amount * np.where(df.negative_amount,-1,1))
                      .groupby('key')['amount_n']
                      .transform(lambda x: sum(x)<=0))
```

Output:

```
   key  amount  amount_0_flag  negative_amount  new_column
0    1     1.0           True            False        True
1    1     1.0           True             True        True
2    2     2.0          False             True       False
3    2     3.0          False            False       False
4    2     4.0          False            False       False
```